# Memory Leaks in iPhone

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

In my application, I am not able to remove the following memory leaks:

```
[NSCFString appendString]

[NSCFString copyWithZone];

[NSDecimalNumberPlaceHolder initWithDecimal]

[SBJsonParser scanRestOfArray]

[SBJsonParser scanRestOfDictionary]

[NSPlaceholderMutableString initWithCapacity]
```

How to remove these leaks?

Comment: Those aren't leaks per se. We need to see how you are dealing with the results of the calls.

Comment: @ Daniel A.White>>>If these are not leaks then what are they because these are showing as leaks in the performance tool..either i should ignore these leaks or how they will be handle...can u please help to sort out the issues....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not leaks caused by system libraries. Leaks tool just points you where is the possible cause of the leak. For example, if you write like this:

```
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString: "some_str"];
```

In this example str is allocated but never released. Leaks tool would show you that there is a leak in    `[NSPlaceholderString initWithCString:]`    but in fact there is leak because you didn't send `release`  message to str.

So a little tip: always search problem in your own code and not in the frameworks you're using.